# Progmatically disable Android voice recognition offensive word filter

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

Does anybody know if there's a way to progmatically disable the "Block offensive words" setting for Android voice recognition?

I know I can do it from my settings but would like to have control of it within the context of the voice recognizing that my application does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. When recognition returns an offensive word it will say a bunch of ****
You only have control over the LANGUAGE_MODEL.

Comment: Ah ok, that's a shame. Thanks!